# Is there a way to change file size limitations for Panel's file uploader when using Pyscript?

Tags: python, html, pyscript, holoviz-panel

Currently using Panel's [FileInput widget](https://panel.holoviz.org/reference/widgets/FileInput.html) in a Pyscript program, and I'm having issues with file size limitations. Per [this link](https://panel.holoviz.org/reference/widgets/FileInput.html#upload-size-limits), it seems like there are potential ways around Panel's default file size, but it unclear how I can make that happen inside the .html Pyscript file.

They have a way via Jupyter Notebook (not applicable) and via "Server context":

```
# your_app.py
import panel as pn

app = ...

MAX_SIZE_MB = 150

pn.serve(
    app,
    # Increase the maximum websocket message size allowed by Bokeh
    websocket_max_message_size=MAX_SIZE_MB*1024*1014,
    # Increase the maximum buffer size allowed by Tornado
    http_server_kwargs={'max_buffer_size': MAX_SIZE_MB*1024*1014}
)
```

... But this code doesn't seem to work inside of the .html

Again, main goal here is to increase Panel's FileInput widget's maximum file size inside a Pyscript .html file.

Comment: In fairness, it says "is not meant to" (not that it isn't viable) and then they provide ways around the default 20MB max upload file size. If WASM limits to what the browser can handle, then, since I'm using chrome (which has a 4GB limit per file), I'm having a hard time understanding why there isn't a potential work around.